# event to be triggered when user leaves ckeditor or page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have been trying to find an event that will trigger when a user leaves the ckeditor window or page in any way, this is because I want to call my save method inside the event so that when the user does try to leave their content is saved. I have inserted a conditional statement with an alert to test if its working but so far the alert hasn't been called signifying that the event I am currently using is not the correct one

here is my code block:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    updateBlockByName(blockname, escape(newhtml), 1, blockid, disableBlogComment);
    if (updateBlockByName) {
        alert('unload save test');
    }
});
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `beforeunload` is broken pretty badly (probably by design) in Blink and it doesn't handle `alert` or other modal dialogs. If you want to display a message, you can use `return`:

```
$( window ).on( 'beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Message for the user';
}
```

It will display a `confirm` dialog with "Leave page" and "Stay on page" buttons.

Moreover, there is also the `unload` event, but it's as unreliable as `beforeunload`. And both of them don't work well on mobile devices.

Probably a good idea is not to rely on detecting the unloading of the page, but rather changes in visibility, via e.g. the `pagehide` event. It will also handle all cases when the user puts your page in the background and simply forgets about it.

A very detailed article about `pagehide`, `beforeunload`, `unload` and other similar events is [available on Ilya Grigorik's site](https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/).

And if you want to detect only leaving the editor, you can probably just listen to [CKEditor's `blur` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur). It's fired when the user moves the cursor outside of the editor.